# Regex to Grab Content of Recursive Parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a template compiler in PHP for my own personal projects and ran into an issue where my `@if` directive doesn't properly grab the contents of the directive if the condition ends with a `)`.

```php
private function handleIf(string $page): string
{
    return preg_replace('/@if ?\( ?(.*?) ?\)(.*?)@endif/is', '<?php if ($1) { ?> $2 <?php } ?>', $page);
}
```

```php
// the directive...
// @if(!empty($title))
// should result in
<?php !empty($title) { ?>
// but is instead rendered as
<?php !empty($title { ?>
// which obviously no worky
```

How would I adjust my regex to match this correctly? It has to be global and multiline since it's part of a template. Is there another method I could use to extract directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given example, you could use a recursive pattern to match balanced parenthesis right after the `@if`.

Note that you are matching php code with a regex that may give unexpected side effects.

```
@if\h*(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))\s*(.*?)\s*@endif\b
```

- `@if\h*` Match `@if` followed by optional spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` Repeat matching any char except `(` or `)` or repeat the first sub pattern
  - `)` Close group 2
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*(.*?)\s*` Capture **group 3**, match any character as few as possible between optional whitespace chars
- `@endif\b` Match `@endif` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZxirs/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Yb7up)

```
$pattern = '/@if\h*(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))\s*(.*?)\s*@endif\b/is';
$s = '@if(!empty($title)). test
and testing   @endif';
$subst = "<?php if($2) { ?>$3<?php } ?>";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $subst, $s);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
<?php if(!empty($title)) { ?>. test
and testing<?php } ?>
```

---

If you don't want to cross another `@if(` in between:

```
@if\h*(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))\s*((?:(?!@if\h*\().)*)\s*@endif\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L0WE0U/1)

Comment: This is a wonderful breakdown, thank you! It is working as expected. I wish I was as magic with Regex as you, fellow.

Answer (score 0):

Can see this code

```
/@if[ ]{0,}\((.*)\)(.*)@endif/gsU
```

input text

```
@if(!empty($title))
     <div>hello</div>
@endif
```

output

```
<?php if ( !empty($title) ) { ?> 
     <div>hello</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

fully code:

```php
<?php //php 7.2.24

function handleIf(string $page): string
{
    return preg_replace('/@if[ ]{0,}\((.*)\)(.*)@endif/isU', '<?php if ( $1 ) { ?> $2 <?php } ?>', $page);
}

$title = "";

$code = '
@if(!empty($title))
     <div>hello</div>
@endif
';

echo handleIf($code);
?>
```

can run via this link
https://rextester.com/DSN63422

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work at all with multiple @if blocks, since it's not lazy-matching the content of the condition parentheses or the body

Comment: @Splashsky add U flag, `'/.../isU'`